# How would you show the effort if the result is negative?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, not-constructive

*Prologue*

Having had this question ([How to learn GUI programming in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796272/how-to-learn-gui-programming-in-f)) closed I was inclined to dispute the reasoning behind the non-constructive decision as being wrong because it is a known problem to those who know the domain. As I looked at the previous meta questions it turns out I asked the same question before ([Question not constructive dependent on field?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136971/question-not-constructive-dependent-on-field)). I am certainly unhappy with the answers there but I won't rehash the exact same argument again. It may help for a bit of context though.

*Question*

The question ([How to learn GUI programming in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796272/how-to-learn-gui-programming-in-f)) was closed to being non-constructive. What are the facts, references or specific expertise that can be shown to demonstrate the lack of existence of GUI tutorials in F# that does not need learning C#?

Comment: I don't mind resource questions, so I cast the first re-open vote.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of **not constructive**

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
>   specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate,
>   arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this
>   question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for
>   guidance.

Shopping questions such as asking for tools and tutorials are **off topic** but they also fall under **not constructive**.

Other `not constructive` questions include `what is the best way to...x` and `Is there a way to make my code cleaner`.

The biggest problem with the **Not Constructive** title is that it confuses users.  It's really a misnomer, and it's just another version of **Off Topic**

Comment: As far as the definition you provide is concerned, this question does not satisfy it. I have just looked up the off topic definition and it doesn't look relevant as well. Can you explain specifically why you think the question is not constructive/off topic even if the facts are provided?

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri your question is a shopping question. Nothing bad about that, but just because it's worthwhile to discuss doesn't mean it's a good fit for SO.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: thanks. That's a concrete answer. I don't agree though: asking for a tool is shopping if there are multiple tools and there is a choice (like in Java, C or Python). F# is a new language and the tools are simply not there. I would understand requesting to verify that there are no choices. But I can't agree with the syntactical reaction that asking for a tutorial or a library is automatically shopping, with no understanding of the circumstances. I wonder how many of the F# questions are closed just because it is a new language so some assumptions are invalid here.

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri Yeah that's frustrating, knowing more about the situation I kind of see your point. Part of it is there are massive numbers of terrible questions, "what tutorial is best for building the next Facebook" type questions, submitted on a regular basis - and in the process of weeding those out it's easy to snag up questions that look like them, but maybe aren't, in a non-obvious way. And since, at a 60 second's reading, your question looks like another polling question for everyone's favorite resources, it got caught up... Mods and close-voters are only human, after all :) cont'd

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri Perhaps if you re-write it to ask about a fairly basic, but concrete task in F#, and maybe subtly ask for input on general approaches in the question, and maybe even explicitly follow up in comments on answers like "by the way where'd you learn this? Oh from this tutorial? great..." I don't know. Might fly under the radar if you disguise it as an actual problem you face.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: thanks. That is actually a positive idea. A concrete task would also be an opportunity to verify if it is of the kind commonly documented in the Internet or if genuine research is done and nothing is there. Easier to mod, so to speak. I will try it the next time I have a question of the sort. Appreciated.